# Sodium metal burning off when conducting electrolysis and I don't know why

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, electrolysis

I melted down some table salt and used high voltage welder power source to try and separate the sodium and chlorine it was partially successful because I could smell and see chlorine gas but during the reaction what I think was sodium would float to the top of the molten salt and burst into flame. Is there a way to prevent this?

I was thinking maybe an airtight crucible, switching the anode and cathode or keeping a lower temperature to prevent it vaporizing. Any answer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

First, sodium burns very nicely in air. However, it also burns in chlorine, returning back to the $\ce{NaCl}$ with which you started.

Most welders provide *alternating* current, meaning the the electrode becomes alternately positive and then negative (50 times per second [50 Hz] in much of the world, and 60 Hz in North America). Therefore, **both** $\ce{Cl2}$ gas and $\ce{Na}$ metal are produced at each electrode and recombining.

To produce sodium metal you need a *direct* current supply, such as from a battery, and some means to *separate* the chlorine bubbling out at the positive (anode) electrode from the sodium metal at the negative (cathode) electrode. A [diagram of the Down's cell](https://www.ck12.org/chemistry/electrolysis-of-molten-salts/lesson/Electrolysis-of-Molten-Salts-and-Electrolysis-of-Brine-CHEM/) should help you understand this, and you can view a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uej2OYBw0RA) of sodium production.

As a demonstration, I've made (for a *very* short time) small amounts of sodium in an open crucible using a laboratory 10 volt, 6 ampere supply... One sees a small metallic bead forming under the molten salt at one wire and immediately burning when it hits the air, with sodium's [characteristic yellow](https://www.chem.uci.edu/~unicorn/249/Handouts/RWFSodium.pdf) glare.